# Windows 10: Cortana crashes

Tags: windows, windows-10, cortana

Today `Cortana` in my Windows 10 started to crash every time I search for something, either using `Start menu` or search bar in `Settings`.

When I type something - I see that both processes `Cortana` and `Cortana Background Task Host` disappear and then return in process list in few seconds.

What can I do about it?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to go to settings, type speech, and there change from microsoft Mark to microsoft Zira

Comment: Haha, I can't "type", Cortana crashes. I found it though, Ease of access > Narrator > Choose a voice. I had "David", changed to "Zira". Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: [create a crash dump](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) and share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it is fixed with Windows commutative update i received today.
So, check your `Settings` > `Update and security` > `Check for updates`.
It might help, it took quite a while for update to arrive.
Though, the solution might not be in update itself but in some system cleanup an update triggers. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Web search history option in Cortana settings.
Open Cortana, hit the hamburger icon, go to notebook, go to settings, then scroll down to "Web search history" and turn it off. I also cleared the device search history while I was at it.

Comment: How does turning off web search solve the author's problem?

Comment: My Cortana is not signed in, I cant find the settings you are talking about when I navigate as you describe, cortana offers me to sign in instead, but I did see some settings like this yesterday, can't find it now, but I am pressy sure the history is disabled.

Answer (score -2):

If updates don't work, hit Win logo key + r and type msconfig if you have changed the startup settings, select normal startup then restart your PC.